# Uncorrelated but not independent random variable

Tags: random-variables, independence, correlation

I have a uniform discrete RV defined as $$X \sim Uni \{-1, 1\}$$. Now, I want to create another uniform random variable from $X$ defined as $Y =X^2$.

Am I right to say the following?

1. $$E[XY] -E[X]E[Y] =E[X^3] - E[X] =0$$
2. $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.
3. $X $ and  $ Y$ are dependent

I want someone to help me confirm this. Much appreciated.

Comment: @geetha290krm That's a typo.

Comment: $Y=1$ because $1^{2}=1$ and $(-1)^{2}=1$. This makes any random variable independent of $Y$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I see! That's true . I missed it.

Comment: Your statements would be correct if $X \sim Uni [-1, 1]$ - a continuous uniform distribution

Answer (score 4):

Consider any random variable $X$ taking values in the set $\{-1,0,1\}$ and has a PMF satisfying: $p_X(-1) = p_X(1) = \rho \in (0,0.5)$.

$\text{Cov}(X,X^2)=\mathbb{E}(X^3) - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(X^2) = 0 - 0\times 2\rho = 0$.

So, $X$ and $X^2$ are uncorrelated.
However, these are not independent because
$\Pr(X=0, X^2=0) = \Pr(X=0) = 1-2\rho \neq (1-2\rho)^2 =\Pr(X=0)\Pr(X^2=0) $

Comment: A nice example of a covriance being $0$ not implying independenc. In the case depicted by the question they are indepent however. But it cannot be deduced from uncorrelation. (sorry for the deletion/rewritting, I missclicked the edit button).